# Problems with Lennard Jones potential parameters reading

Tags: interatomic-potentials, reproducing-data-from-papers

So I was given [this link](https://openkim.org/files/MO_959249795837_003/LennardJones612_UniversalShifted.params), and was happy that I have now the epsilons and sigmas that I can use in Lennard-Jones potential calculations, but found out that the information in other sources is very different.

It says [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Specific_Interactions/Lennard-Jones_Potential):

> "The  ϵ  and  σ  values for Xenon (Xe) are found to be 1.77 kJ/mol and 4.10 angstroms, respectively."

Which is different from the table in first link which says epsilon = 0.0238880 eV (2.304881456 kJ/mol) and sigma = 2.4945200 angstroms.

I understand that there could be some insignificant differences, but these are rather big ones. Maybe I am not correctly reading the table (ignoring cutoff) or something else?

Comment: I'm not certain if this makes a difference, but your first link points to parameters for a shifted-LJ, where the energy values are shifted down by the energy value at some cutoff distance. I don't see how this would affect $\sigma$, but it may change the fit for $\epsilon$. The OpenKim model at least points sources for it's parameters in the README file. The ChemLibre text may have just made up values for the sake of example problems.

Comment: Its not just ChemLibre, but you might be right. Can I use the cutoff value to get more precise results?

Comment: +1 but I agree with Tyberius. The OpenKim data comes with references to publications whereas the ChemLibre data is just for some example problem in a textbook. Why not just use the OpenKim values and move on to the more exciting parts of your project? Since [you are doing this as part of making a computer game](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4826/5), why do the sigma and epsilon values matter so much?

Comment: @NikeDattani you probably right ;) .. I will move on

Comment: Using cut or cut+shift can lead to very significant differences in results. If you are doing molecular dynamics, it is standard to use the shift, so that your force is smooth at the cut point. Where you cut at also makes a difference. make sure to cut at least 2.5*sigma, but for chemical potential calculations, cut at 5*sigma or more